# Session callback with no value in NextAuth.js

Tags: session, next.js, callback, jwt, next-auth

Please can somebody help me with this issue in NextAuth.I am implementing authentication with CredentialsProvider in NextAuth. But I have a problem with a session callback. here is a bit of my code. After get a userdata from authorize.
I am using also typescript in my project

```
const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  // Providers/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: "Credentials",
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {},
      authorize: async (
        credentials: { username: string; password: string },
        req
      ) => {
        // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
        if (credentials && credentials.username && credentials.password) {
          // Any object returned will be saved in `user` property of the JWT
          try {
            const { data } = await axios({
              method: "post",
              url: `${API_URL}/api/users/login/tokens/`,
              data: {
                username: credentials.username,
                password: credentials.password,
              },
            });

            return data;
          } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error.response.data.detail);
          }
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],

  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },

  // Callbacks  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  callbacks: {
    //async signIn({user, account,profile}){return true}
    //async redirect({url, baseUrl}){return baseUrl}

    jwt: async ({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) => {
      if (user) {
        //...logic to construct and return a token
        token.userData = user;

        console.log(token);

        return Promise.resolve(token);
      }
    },

    session: async ({ session, token, user }) => {
      session.user = user;

      console.log(token);
      //console.log(user);
      //console.log(session);

      return Promise.resolve(session);
    },
  },
```

The returned token of jwt callback works well. accordnly documentation the returned token of jwt must be available automatically in th session callback. But with that session callback I have two issues.

First in my session callback I cannot get the value of token or user. when I logged token inside session callback, I obtain undefined. but when I logged it inside jwt callback it works well and I get user data. i don't know why this happens.

Secondly the session callback render twice

Please can someone help me to fix this?
I have read many tutorial even here on StackOverflow. I reproduce advices but my own code does not running.

Comment: Were you able to figure out root cause?